# Adding Marker to Google Map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm creating a map using the Javascript API, and I'm having some trouble getting the markers to show up.

I've followed this tutorial to create the map, which works well:

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

I've then followed this tutorial to add the marker, but it's not loading:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Here's my code now:

```
            <script>
        function initialize() {
            var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
            var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.643296, -79.408475),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options, marker);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Hello World!" });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options, marker);
```

is wrong. `map`constructor has only two arguments. It should be

```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
```

And `myLatlng` is not defined. So, you can change your code to:

```
function initialize() {
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.643296, -79.408475);

    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var map_options = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this url you will get your answer     http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_overlays.asp